# OQL syntax for counting Strings matching criteria

Tags: java, visualvm, jvisualvm, oql

Please help me. I analyse my heap dump in VisualVM.

How can I get amount of all Strings  with value == "0"?
I have the following query:

```
select count(s) from java.lang.String s where s.toString().equals("0");
```

But it doesnt work.
I want to receive amount of all Strings with "0" value  and if it's possible their size in memory.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's solved my problem

```
select count(heap.objects('java.lang.String'), "it.toString().equals('0')")
```